# Inline data representation

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

I would like to represent data that gives an overview but allows them to drill down in an inline fashion - so if you had a grouping of say 6 objects the user could expand the data and it would show the 6 objects immeadiately below it before any more high level data.

It would appear that MSHFlexgrid gives this ability but I can't find any information about actually using it, or what it's limitations are (can you have differing number of fields and/or can they have different spacing, what about column headers, indentation at for the start, etc).

I found [this site](http://visualbasic-programming.blogspot.com/2007/11/hierarchical-flexgrid-control.html), but the images are broken (in ie8 and ff3.5). Google searches show people just using the flat data representation but nothing using the hierarchical properties). **Does anyone know any good tutorials or forums with a good discussion about pitfalls?**

Due to lack of information about using it, I am thinking of coding my own version but if anyone has done work in this area I haven't found it - I would of thought it would be a natural wish for data representation. **If someone has coded a version of this (any language) then I wouldn't mind reading about it** - maybe my idea of how to do it wouldn't be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [vbAccelerator](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Controls/TreeView/Multi-Column_TreeView_Control/article.asp).  He has a Multi-Column Treeview control that sounds like what you may be looking for.  He gives you the source and has some pretty decent samples.

Comment: This is similar to what I would like but with differing number of columns for the overview and detailed view. I will look into this further.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSHFlexGrid reference pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228851(VS.60).aspx) and the ["using the MSHFlexGrid"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241752(VS.60).aspx) topic in the Visual Basic manual?
Sorry if you've already looked at these!

Comment: I'd seen the second - which you list erroneously as an example - but not the first. Nor do they show how to use the heirarchical feature of the grid.